# Magento 2 SOAP import makes ugly urls. How can I fix it?

Tags: magento2, soap

An external system is making requests to `/soap/all?services=catalogProductRepositoryV1`. Products are imported. So far so good.

But the `url key` is encoded in an ugly way.

```
<attributeCode>url_key</attributeCode>
<value>Test Product (Example)</value>
</item>
```

Becomes `Test%20Product%20%28Example%29`

I would like it to be more like:

`test-product-example`

Should be an easy fix. But I cannot find the code where all this is handled?

Questions:

- Is there an easy way to manage this? Maybe a configuration option or something?
- Where is the module/code responsible to handle the save of an `url_key` attribute from a SOAP request?
- What is the best way to capture and replace the behavior? Writing a custom plugin maybe?